# Apple Watch notification center

Tags: apple-push-notifications, watchkit, apple-watch

What is that notification's in the notification center called? Is it just notifications?

**How to view it:** After a notification shows up: ignore the notification, go to the watch home screen, go to the clock app screen, drag from the top to the bottom of the screen to see the notification center.

We will see a notification with the title and the alertBody of the notification. When we click on that notification it will take us to a (Static) long look notification. **What is that notification called int he center?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe they have a special name, it's just notifications.

If you are talking about dragging from the *bottom to the top*, you'll see a list of `Glances`. However, these have nothing to do with the notifications directly (the developer might have these display the latest information, which might be the same as in the notification, but they're not directly related)